# How can i add a click counter to my download page on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, counter

I have a page with a list of cd's  and mixtapes and each cd is downloadable with a download button....
i want to count and display how many times each download button is click....
i have searches for days and can't seem to figure it out??
if anyone could help me out that would be great...

here is the code for the links on my wordpress site

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'mixtape_link',true); ?>" class="button small"><span>Download Now!</span></a>
```

i would like each link to count AND display how many times it has been clicked

Answer (score 0):

Use the onclick event to call a is function. With that function call for a php file to increment a counter in a text file or in your database.

This is a very short plain example.
JavaScript:

```
function increment() { 

$.ajax ({ url: "www.link.to/yourphpfile.php", 

data: { action : increment }, //optional 

}
```

PHP file:

```
if ($_POST["action"] == "increment") {

// increment your counter

}
```

This is not a complete example. You need to use a special solution for that in worpress. Take a look at this: 
 http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: so would i put this on the albums template pâge 

<script>function increment() {

$.ajax ({ url: "www.link.to/yourphpfile.php",

data: { action : increment }, //optional

}</script>

Comment: This won't work, all requests in wordpress are redirected to `index.php` you must use the api http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: would you be able to post an example using the code i provided?